# Cassandra: mixing hosts?

Tags: cassandra

Im trying to understand capacity planning for a putative Cassandra network. I have brought up a test group using a mixture of hosts (RHEL, Win64, etc) and it seemed fine. Im wondering how feasible this sort of thing is long-term. IE how do I define the smallest acceptable node? Whats the effect of adding large, powerful nodes to an installation with smaller nodes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mixing different platforms (Windows/Unix) is not supported.  It might work, but it probably will bite you at some point, and it's a bad idea anyway -- the more homogenous your environment, the less factors you need to consider when troubleshooting.

Cassandra does allow you to load balance across hosts of different capacities; see [the operations wiki page](http://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/Operations).

Comment: RE: 'mixing' Is it the platform difference that matters or the capacity / config of the host(s)? Seems like java should be java should be java.. etc..

Comment: "Mixing different platforms is not supported." As hard as Java tries to pretend the OS doesn't matter, it still does. :)

Comment: I was also thinking along the lines java is java... The plan was to mix Solaris and GNU/Linux machines, would you recommend against this? The goal is to replace the Solaris machines with CentOS, one at a time, is there anything that makes you think that this will break?