# Two node Cassandra cluster (at latest rev) fails with "Not a time-based UUID"

Tags: cassandra

I've been running a one node cassandra cluster (on windows) at 1.1.3.
I added a 2nd node (on ubuntu) also at 1.1.3.

When I start the first node all is well, but when I start the second node I get an error on the first node:  "UnsupportedOperationException: Not a time-based UUID.

Researching this error it seems like an error one might get if mixing older and newer cassandras in the same cluster but thats not the case here.

The cassandra.yaml files on the two machines are vanilla (i.e. unchanged from download except for relevant IP addresses).

Any suggestions appreciated.

Comment: Since I couldn't find any documentation on it I've verified that 1.1.3 allows mixing Windows and Ubuntu nodes without seeing this problem.  So I'm at a loss to see where this error is coming from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, mixing nodes with different OS in the same cluster isn't supported.

[Read this answer by jbellis, one of the Cassandra creators](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7353159/964592)

Comment: If as the Cassandra creators state mixing nodes on different OSs isn't supported and if it works at all only by accident, then I'd humbly suggest that this be made a tad more obvious in the documentation :-)

Comment: I agree. I tried mixing nodes once myself with no luck. Got the same reply on the Cassandra mailing list.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why this is happening is because of little-endian vs big-endian on Windows machines vs Unix.